# User name field changed back by passwd

Tags: freebsd

I am finishing installing a amd 64 FreeBSD 11.1 with Gnome 3.

When I configured there a user, I did not input the User Name field; so I was perplexed when GDM booted, and showed me a user as "User &"; it turned out `passwd` filled it that way.

The thing is that I edited `/etc/passwd` to put there a proper name; and GDM showed it properly.

However upon changing the password of that user with `passwd` as root, the user name field was changed back to "User &".

I have not yet tested if using `chfn` will fix it for good, will test it at home.

However, I am very quite curious, where is that "User &" coming or being restored from?

Comment: `&` in the field containing the full name of the user will usually be replaced with the capitalised username (according to `passwd(5)`). I don't know why GDM doesn't grok it properly or why it seemingly gets reverted when you change it though.

Comment: @Kusalananda It happened very late yesterday, will investigate a bit more at home today and edit a little more the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not edit `/etc/passwd` as it is not the master copy - use `vipw` instead.

See [the manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vipw) for more.

Comment: I know `vipw` thanks for the hint. I will investigate more that is happening behind the scenes later on, will keep you posted.